# Doing several things at the same time in Rviz

Tags: navigation, mapping, kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I wrote a program to move my urdf model around Rviz. It works fine when I have **/odom (xyz yaw) on Fixed Frame** and **/base_link (principal link of my urdf model) on Target Frame** thanks to this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher).

I would like to add a point cloud from a Kinect but when I add a point cloud with any topics from the /openni_camera, I have an error on my pointcloud2 topic:

***No transform to fixed frame [/odom]. TF error: [Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame] to frame [/odom]]***

That is quite understandable but how can I add a point cloud if I want to move my robot? Should I send everything on the same topic? kind of messy and not even sure it will work...

Thank you for giving me any leads

Brioche

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44183/doing-several-things-at-the-same-time-in-rviz/) by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a valid tf tree that also contains the frame `/openni_rgb_optical_frame`. This is normally done by creating a urdf file of your robot (have a look at [these tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials)) and running the [robot_state_publisher](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher). The state publisher will read your urdf file and publish the links in it as tf frames. Then rviz will visualize the point cloud in the right frame.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-09-20**:
Yes but I also make my robot move by publishing its position on /odom (http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) so I don't understand how I can connect my /odom and /openni_rgb_optical_frame ... When I read tf it's not really clear for me... sorry

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-20**:
I assume the node for publishing your odometry information is publishing a transform from /odom to your robot's root link, e.g. /base_link. As Lorenz says, you then need to have a transform from the point cloud's reference frame (e.g. /openni_rgb_optical_frame) to your robot's root frame. ...

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-20**:
You can do this by using the mentioned robot_state_publisher in combination with a URDF file. Or, for a simple test, you can also use the [static transform publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher) to publish the transform robot's root frame -> point cloud's reference frame

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-20**:
RViz will combine the provided information to visualise the point cloud linked to the moving robot.

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-10-01**:
Thanks, so if I well understood, I should modify my cpp to have /optical_..._frame as my header.frame_id and odom and base_link as child_frame_id. (according to the robot state publisher tuto) I will try it tomorrow

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-01**:
It is ok to set openni_optical_frame as header.frame_id of your point cloud. But make sure that your urdf file contains a link that is also named openni_optical frame. Then make sure you run the robot_state_publisher node. It will publish a tf tree generated from your urdf.

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-10-04**:
For the curious: I've tranformed my /odom in /openni_rgb_optical_frame and not my base_link this /odom was my header.id and now I have my robot moving and my kinect point cloud! Thanks a lot bit-pirate and Lorenz